# Samsung phones - Do their camera lens have a coating?

Tags: samsung, camera

I have the samsung a32 5g.
Do the front and back cameras on these phones have any coating similar to what professional cameras have like "anti glare?" Does alcohol damage these coatings or is it ok if it has any?